# Describing AWS SSM parameters using tags failing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-ssm

I am running a lambda to fetch ssm parameters in AWS and I want to filter using tags. I have tried the method recommended by aws but I keep getting this error:

"***errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DescribeParameters operation: An error occurred while calling one AWS dependency service.***"

Any help as to why?
reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/parameter-search.html
https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/tests/test_ssm/test_ssm_boto3.py#L1043-L1045

This is the code that I am running:

```css
import json
import boto3

ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print("Fetch group A ssm parameter: ")
    
    leg_one_parameter = ssm_client.describe_parameters(
        ParameterFilters=[{"Key": "tag:group", "Values":["A"]}]
        )['Parameters']
    
    parameter_name = list(map(lambda parameter: parameter['Name'], leg_one_parameter))
   
    return parameter_name
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Validation error may be produced by a bug in the boto3... Once or twice I had a similar issue.

I tried to execute your request and it passed.

```
leg_one_parameter = ssm.describe_parameters(
    ParameterFilters=[{"Key": "tag:group", "Values":["A"]}]
    )['Parameters']
leg_one_parameter
[]
```

I used boto3 in version 1.24.3